# Post Sorting By Vote Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, acts-as-votable

I have a page where users can add favorites. Right now the page sorts their posts into favorites but sorts them by .order(created_at: :desc) for the Post databases created_at field. How can I change this to use the Vote table and its created_at frield.

```
@posts = Post.where(id: current_user.find_voted_items.map(&:id)).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 36)
```

Here is the relevant schema

```
create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "votable_id"
  t.string   "votable_type"
  t.integer  "voter_id"
  t.string   "voter_type"
  t.boolean  "vote_flag"
  t.string   "vote_scope"
  t.integer  "vote_weight"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "soundcloud"
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "artist"
  t.string   "audio"
  t.string   "image"
  t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
  t.string   "download"
  t.integer  "cached_votes_total",      default: 0
  t.integer  "cached_votes_score",      default: 0
  t.integer  "cached_votes_up",         default: 0
  t.integer  "cached_votes_down",       default: 0
  t.integer  "cached_weighted_score",   default: 0
  t.integer  "cached_weighted_total",   default: 0
  t.float    "cached_weighted_average", default: 0.0
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the posts, it makes more sense to use the posts database. If you want to return all of the votes for one post using the vote database instead, you could try something like this:
`@votes = Vote.where(votable_id: some_post.id).order('created_at DESC')`

But I'm not sure I understand what you would like to return from the Vote database.